# Sending Email if Values are between two numbers

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to see if i can send an email based on whether or not a value is between two different values.  IE: If value is >200 and <239 trigger email.

```
function sendMaileditbt200239(e){
if (e.range.columnStart != 26 || e.value < 200  > 239) return;
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,44).getValues();
let firstname = rData[0][3]; //row of first name
let lastname = rData[0][2]; //row of last name
let tbcid = rData[0][1]; //row of TEA ID number
let phnum = rData[0][4]; //row of TEA ID number
let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
let msg = "Status: BILLING  Name: " + firstname + " " + lastname + " Tel:" + phnum + " TBC ID:         
" +    tbcid + " Approved at " + now + ".";
Logger.log(msg);
MailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "Greater Then 200 less than 249", msg);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sendMaileditbt200239(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 26 && e.value > 200 && e.value < 239) {
    const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
    let firstname = rData[0][3]; //row of first name
    let lastname = rData[0][2]; //row of last name
    let tbcid = rData[0][1]; //row of TEA ID number
    let phnum = rData[0][4]; //row of TEA ID number
    let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
    let msg = "Status: BILLING  Name: " + firstname + " " + lastname + " Tel:" + phnum + " TBC ID:         
    " +    tbcid + " Approved at " + now + ".";
    Logger.log(msg);
    MailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "Greater Then 200 less than 249", msg);
  }
}
```